# Ansible (read_csv): How to convert entire CSV column into a list efficiently without loop?

Tags: csv, ansible

I've a CSV (circa 2200 rows) with around 8 columns. For simplicity below is a snapshot

```
ID,fruit,currency
11,mango,USD
12,peach,GBP
13,apricot,EUR
```

The aim is to get the `fruit` column as an **list** and write to another file

```
["mango","peach","apricot"]
```

I've done it using loop, but this take ages to loop through larger list (below is the concept i've done)

```
    - name: "Read as a list"
      read_csv:
        path: ./fruit.csv
      register: mycsv

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ item.fruit| join (',') }}'
      loop: "{{mycsv.list}}"
```

Is there a efficient/better way to convert/translate above read_csv specific column into a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```yaml
fruit: "{{ mycsv.list|map(attribute='fruit')|list }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
fruit: [mango, peach, apricot]
```